# gajim blinking trayicon notification

Tags: gajim, tray

Gajim has a (nasty) trayicon notification option that blinks the Gajim icon when you have new messages.  You can cancel this behaviour via the ACE's `trayicon_notification_on_events` option.  But what I would like to do is to change the icon to something else but **not** blink.  Is that possible?

**Edit**: Version 0.15.1 *should* have fixed it but has not.

```
; pwd           
/home/****/src/gajim-0.15.1
; grep -ri trayicon_blink *
;
```

The patch appears not to be included in the source tar ball.

Comment: From a look at the current gajim sources on my machine, the answer is probably "not without patching the program".

Getting rid of the blinking "feature" requires commenting out one line, changing the icon in this case is a bit more complicated because you'd have to make and load the new icon.
If you're familiar with python and interested, I can point you to the code that would need changing.

Comment: @Bristol: bleurgh, I am not sure I want to keep patching all version of gajim and I seriously doubt that it would be accepted as a patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changeset [fe49adb8ec1c](http://hg.gajim.org/gajim/rev/fe49adb8ec1c) (Aug 14) added ACE's `trayicon_blink` whose [description](http://hg.gajim.org/gajim/rev/fe49adb8ec1c#l1.7) is: *If False, Gajim will display a static event icon instead of the blinking status icon in the notification area when notifying on event.*

You can wait for a release that includes that change (I did think 0.15.1 included it) or run Gajim from source.

Running from source is trivial, given that you don't need to build the code. Just:

```
$ hg clone http://hg.gajim.org/gajim/
$ cd gajim
$ ./launch.sh
```

Don't miss [optional runtime requirements](http://hg.gajim.org/gajim/file/e5ad3e5e0d51/README.html#l21).

Comment: -1, see edited question.

Comment: Odd, I run gajim from source myself and did think that changeset was reachable because I saw it when listing [gajim_0.15 branch](http://hg.gajim.org/gajim/shortlog/14025?revcount=120). Answer edited.